# urldecode and pluses - PHP

Tags: php, urldecode

I have a form field that I plonk a query string into.

This is cleaned in so far as it is urldecoded and then I throw in htmlentities so it doesn't create flawed HTML.

In other words:

```
<input type="text" name="example" value="<?php echo htmlentities((urldecode($_GET["example"])); ?>" />
```

`urldecode` converts plusses into spaces, however someone may wish to use a genuine plus in their query.

Two questions:

1. is the above 'secure' enough in terms of injection etc.
2. is there an alternative to `urldecode` which will not convert the genuine plus

Comment: $_GET should already be urldecode'd for you.  You shouldn't need to urldecode it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The strings in the `$_GET` array are already urldecoded. You should not do it againt.

On the other hand, if you really want to insert a plus into the querystring, you should urlencode it first.